# My summon command says (about 50% of the time) unable to summon object minecraft 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For some reason half the time I activate a `/summon` command it just says "unable to summon object", but it still works half the time. This is only with this summon command, `/summon chicken` works.

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~3 ~ {CustomName:"Enemy",CustomNameVisible:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",Count:1b,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{color:0}}}],HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:bow",Count:1b,tag:{Unbreakable:1,ench:[{id:48,lvl:2999}]}},{id:"minecraft:totem_of_undying",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"Life",Lore:["For Another Life"]}}}],ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.0F],HandDropChances:[0.0F,2.0F],UUIDLeast:0L,UUIDMost:0L,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:2999,Duration:100,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

This command also:

```
/summon skeleton ~ ~2 ~ {CustomName:"Enemy",CustomNameVisible:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",Count:1b,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{color:0}}}],HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:bow",Count:1b,tag:{Unbreakable:1,ench:[{id:48,lvl:2999}]}},{id:"minecraft:totem_of_undying",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"Life",Lore:["For Another Life"]}}}],ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.0F],HandDropChances:[0.0F,2.0F],UUIDLeast:2L,UUIDMost:2L,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:2999,Duration:100,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

Comment: If you are curious, i'm using this for a 2 in the chamber (used to be 1 but you can just farm enemies so i made everything have 2 lives) mini-game for my map which already has tons of super, awesome, fun mini-games.

Comment: Try a shorter command first, then add details.

Comment: have you tried to use your command in open air? this error usually occurs when the location at which the entity is summoned is obstructed by blocks.

Answer (score 3):

so... I rewrote your first command so that it is more readable:

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~3 ~ 
{
    CustomName:"Enemy",
    CustomNameVisible:1,
    ArmorItems:
    [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {
            id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",
            Count:1b,
            tag:
            {
                Unbreakable:1,
                display:
                {
                    color:0
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    HandItems:
    [
        {
            id:"minecraft:bow",
            Count:1b,
            tag:
            {
                Unbreakable:1,
                ench:
                [
                    {id:48,lvl:2999}
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            id:"minecraft:totem_of_undying",
            Count:1b,
            tag:
            {
                display:
                {
                    Name:"Life",
                    Lore:["For Another Life"]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.0F],
    HandDropChances:[0.0F,2.0F],
    UUIDLeast:0L,UUIDMost:0L,
    ActiveEffects:
    [
        {Id:11,Amplifier:2999,Duration:100,ShowParticles:0b}
    ]
}
```

All your brackets are balanced, so that's all fine. I do notice that some of the values don't have a type identifier behind them, which isn't Always necessary, but I usually just do it. It's good practice.

You give this skeleton both a UUIDLeast of 0 and a UUIDMost of 0
Notice that UUID stands for Unique User ID. This means that every entity needs a unique UUID. You are summoning skeletons with the same UUID, which is not possible.

But further than that, your command looks completely fine.

Comment: `You're summoning the skeleton 3 blocks above the command block. If this location is obstructed by blocks, then no entity can be summoned there.` That is not correct. Entities can be summoned inside blocks without any issue. They cannot, however, be summoned outside loaded chunks. The UUID is likely the primary issue instead.

Comment: @Skylinerw thank you for correcting me. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help me it means alot hopefully this can also help other people who come to this websight to i will make sure that there is only one mob with the UUID. :) thanks so much

Comment: @xXSPENCERXxxXSPENCERXx well... If my answer helped you, then please accept it using the check mark. It will reward me for helping you and other people can see that your question has an answer. :)

Comment: sry i wanted to earlier but at the time i didnt have a reputation of 15

Answer (score -1):

Have you been using a command block? If you are using this command in regular chat, it may not work depending on the command since I believe there is a character limit. If this is the case, you can get a command block with `/give @p command_block`.

Comment: Sadly i am using command blocks when i activate it, sometimes it works but usually it says unable to summon object even if i dont make any changes to the command block it's like a 75/25 chance but sometimes it feels like 50/50... Thanks for your answer though : )

Comment: Does anyone know how i could get an answer from someone like skilinerw? Or someone similiar to him?